# Spring Boot upgrade can't add RequestContextListener

Tags: spring-boot

So I just upgraded my Spring Boot web app to 2.0.0,  In my main Application class I have this method:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    WebApplicationContext rootAppContext = createRootApplicationContext(servletContext);
    if (rootAppContext != null) {
        servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
    }
    else {
        logger.debug("No ContextLoaderListener registered");
    }   
}
```

But now I am getting a compile error:

```
The method addListener(RequestContextListener) is undefined for the type ServletContext
```

What's weird is that the ServletContext is the problem, not Spring boot.  It no longer has any add* methods.  Did Spring5/Boot2  upgrade the servlet specs, and
What is the correct way to do this now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a ServletContext issue.  Spring boot 2 uses servlet specs 3.1.0,  and apparently no longer support 2.5,  which is what I had in my pom. So I replaced it with this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And it worked fine.  Hope this helps someone.